# Setting password for user via wp cli for MariaDB

Tags: wordpress, mariadb, wp-cli

How to set this password with wp cli `CzTd#&h@!764DQP%$*gpW%*9)`?

I tried following, but it does not work:

```
$ wp user update 123 --user_pass=CzTd#&h@!764DQP%$*gpW%*9)
```

It won't recognize the special characters and barfs. Or, it cuts off the password at the first special char and sets the password as `CzTd`

Comment: I do not have experience in wordpress, but most of time put string between single or double quotes would works on other cli commands.  `wp user update 123 --user_pass="CzTd#&h@!764DQP%$*gpW%*9)"`

Comment: try with `"CzTd#&h@!764DQP%$*gpW%*9)"` I am sure that should work! otherwise use single `'CzTd#&h@!764DQP%$*gpW%*9)'`. Putty should have nothing to do with that!

Comment: tried single quotes and didn't work. will try double quote and get back to you. thanks

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   double quotes worked!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "CzTd#&h@!764DQP%$*gpW%*9)"

Comment: single quotes did not work

Comment: NO!  In *nix, double quotes expands various things inside the quotes.  In some shells, it will replace `!764` with command number 764 that you executed in the session.  This will set your password to something, but you probably won't know what!  `$*` is also likely to be expanded.